# The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly, Xamarin.Android VS 2015 PC only

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

This Xamarin.Forms.Android project builds fine using Xamarin Studio Mac or Visual Studio Mac.
In attempt to consolidate all builds using Visual Studio 2015 for PC, I can successfully build the same exact codebase for iOS, WinPhone 8.1, and UWP .

The android project is the only one that is failing. I've cleaned the obj/bin dirs.

**Error:**

```
The "ConvertResourcesCases" task failed unexpectedly.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '[fullpath]\Droid\obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml.tmp' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged(String source, String destination)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.MonoAndroidHelper.CleanBOM(String filePath)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.FixupResources(ITaskItem item, Dictionary`2 acwMap)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.FixupResources(Dictionary`2 acwMap)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ConvertResourcesCases.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() EmployeePortal.Droid
```

Comment: Try running VS as administrator, because from what I'm seeing, on the first line it fails due to Access Denied to the styles.xml.tmp file.

Comment: Still seeing the same error running as admin. I am noticing that styles.xml exists but styles.xml.tmp does not...

Comment: Can you please check the permissions of the folder you are in? This may be a folder from another user or something that you shouldn't have access to and Visual Studio can't get to it, please just confirm that.

Comment: I'm the owner and the permissions on that folder are now wide open and I'm still seeing the error. I then pointed the build to a different folder still with no luck.  styles.xml.tmp is not being created. There is a Xamarin bug related to this but they claim it's fixed....